# NodeJS '@azure/storage-blob': How do set Blob Service Properties when uploading a file

Tags: node.js, azure-blob-storage, content-disposition, azure-node-sdk

From [this document](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@azure/storage-blob), there is no example to set Blob Service Properties.

Below is my Sample Code:

```
let containerClient = blobServiceClient.getContainerClient(CONTAINERNAME),
    blockBlobClient = containerClient.getBlockBlobClient(BLOBNAME);

await blockBlobClient.uploadFile(FILEPATH);
```

Please advise how I can upload a file with setting `contentDisposition` and `contentType` in `properties` of blockBlob.

Comment: Does this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63659297/set-content-type-to-image-in-javascript-v10-sdk-nodejs) helpful to you?

Comment: Seems yes, will test it tomorrow, thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please try this way:

```
    const blobOptions = { blobHTTPHeaders: { blobContentType: 'image/jpeg', blobContentDisposition: "attachment; filename=package.jpg" } };
    const uploadBlobResponse =await blockBlobClient.uploadFile(filePath,blobOptions);
```

If there are other questions, please let me know!

Comment: May I know how to handle exception like there is outage of Azure service?
e.g. there is errorHandler defined in serviceBus: `receiver.registerMessageHandler(onMessageHandler, onErrorHandler);`

Comment: Hi, @DaiKeung. I don't know this problem very well, because there are many Azure services, maybe you can ask a question in stack overflow, but it's better to be specific to a certain service. In addition, the most common way to handle exceptions is to use `try...catch...`, you can refer to this [official document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-error-pages).